# Library for in browser chat client like fb chat or gchat over the xmpp protocol?

Tags: php, zend-framework, xmpp, ejabberd, libjingle

I am trying to build a chat service within my site which will let users chat with their "friends" on the site.  Their "friends" will be decided internally from a mysql database. The chat application should look like gchat where once a contact is clicked on, a tab on the bottom pops up and you are ready to chat.

Are there any good libraries which would allow for such functionality?  Preferably ones that run over an ejabberd server although it can be something else.  If not, what would be the best way of implementing such an in browser chat app in a zend/php framework?

Thanks

Edit:
After some more research I have come across libjingle.  Would that be the kind of library that I am looking for? Or can anyone tell me more about libjingle and its uses?

Comment: libjingle is a C library for Jingle, the XMPP extension for voice-video. It won't work in a web browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used  [strophe.js](https://github.com/metajack/strophejs) for my site. This [book](http://professionalxmpp.com/) was really helpful for me.

Comment: I was just going to edit asking about strophe.  Thanks very much.  I will look into this. If you don't mind me asking what kind of mechanism did you use strophe for and how long did it take to implement?

Comment: I used ejabberd as server. The book i mentioned was really helpful for me. All the requirement you have are worked out(with code example) in that book. If you know javascript, it will be really easy for you. For me it took around one month to implement the basic stuff(i was working on it as part time).